# List of ERB tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, erb

I found today this definition in my `.erb` files:

```
<%=t '.title', :default => model_class.model_name.human.pluralize %>
```

or

```
<%=l post.created_at, :format => "%d %b. %Y" %>
```

I was able to figure out, that `<%=t` has something to do with translations. However I was unable to find any explanation of `<%=l`.

You can answer what `<%=l` is for. But what I'm looking for is a comprehensive list of all ERB tags available in RoR 3.1. I searched hard, but I was unable to find list like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`l` is shorthand for `localize`

- Read the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#the-public-i18n-api) on this
- Read the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Translation.html#method-i-localize)
- View the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6e26be69606c52dbccfad366661b455157c35be4/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/translation.rb#L8)

`<%=l` is *not* an ERB "tag" it's simply `<%=` (print) **+** `l(post.created_at, :format => "%d %b. %Y)` (localized format of `:created_at` attribute of `post`.

Comment: Thanks. So that way I can use any function available in current scope using that syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Those are methods. 't' is short for 'translate' and 'l' for 'localize' as seen here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#the-public-i18n-api